# libgdx desktop multiple textures multiple shaders

Tags: libgdx, textures, shader, desktop

I'd like to ask for help or tutorials. I've googled with several keywords, none of them gave me the result i was looking for. I'm trying to achieve to render multiple textures in one frame, with multiple shaders. For now i have a Grayscale and a Blur shader working. I read through most of the tutorials [here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki), and some others. But all i found where for a single image, not a whole sets of textures.

Lets say i've got something like this, where

- A is the Screen
- B is a Font (BitmapFont)
- C to F are the textures

[image]

Now i would like to render each texture differently.

- B gets a GrayScale shader
- C gets a Blur shader ( i got this - quite simple, but the code is not reusable)
- D gets GrayScale and a Blur (same as above)
- E to F are staying as they where ( i got this... easy)
- Finally A gets a Blur shader again.

I appreciate any help i get.

Comment: First, draw sprites C and D each to their own frame buffers and blur them. Then in a new frame buffer that's the size of the screen: `spriteBatch.setShader(grayScaleShader); spriteBatch.begin(); spriteBatch.draw(bitmapFontCacheB); spriteBatch.draw(frameBufferD); spriteBatch.setShader(null); spriteBatch.draw(frameBufferC); spriteBatch.draw(spriteE); spriteBatch.draw(spriteF);  spriteBatch.end();` Then blur this frame buffer and draw it to the screen.

Comment: I thought spriteBatch.draw() draws on the screen? or do i have to create multiple sprite batches?

Comment: It draws on whatever you want it to. Do `spriteBatch.begin()` and `.end()` in between `frameBuffer.begin()` and `.end()` and it will draw to that frame buffer. You can use the same sprite batch repeatedly on as many different frame buffers as you like.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i guess you should add this as an answer, it seems to be the right solution and you explained it verry well.